# Azure Application Insights KQL - How to accumulate values?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I would like to accumulate values by timestamp in a ever growing manner.

The following query

```
ContainerLog
| extend logsize = string_size(LogEntry)
| summarize sum(logsize) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1m)
| render timechart
```

generates a graph that goes up and down:
[image]
I would like to add the previous value with the current value, this way generating an always growing graph symbolizing the total amount of requests up to that moment.

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rowcumsumfunction for running totals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let ContainerLog = materialize(range i from 1 to 15 step 1 | extend TimeGenerated = ago(7d*rand()), logsize = rand(1000));
// Solution starts here.
ContainerLog
| summarize sum(logsize) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1m)
| order by TimeGenerated asc
| extend accumulated_sum_logsize = row_cumsum(sum_logsize)
| render timechart
```

[image: Graph]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/demo12.westus/databases/GitHub?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WOu27DMAxFd3/FHa0iiO2h6FB06tCl6NLuBmMxjgBLNCQafSAfXzoNCmcTdclzT9PgneI8MTwpYeTEmTRI2uNNFDNlhRyhJ0aRabkk1cSKZ0lKwbZfZcQTIinnQFP44TpTGhkBxywRHVTQ3aMozzacwV/KyeMjRH75a2NvABqlfvB3dutr53aYZCwGs%20Ty1bVt69xj1Zjv1cOQZldw4sz7autTnVGWGCmvAHvVV5jD4RuHkOqb8h266OxEsue8btyqURmqf2sahiUu0xr0Bu43lvLZW7a2bYKVm%203QwGrU4WTGv94Mu7NzAQAA)

P.S.
I kept `sum_logsize` for learning purposes.
In your scenario it can be removed.